# Honda Contact Points Breaker Stuck Closed

Tags: honda, starting, repair, vintage, points

In troubleshooting starting issues I found that the points breaker on my 1974 125XL is fused shut. Beyond soaking it in pb blaster (which has been my approach thus far) any recommendations for freeing this up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fused breaker points implies WELDED breaker points. The electrical activity which causes pitting has exceeded operational limits and has likely bonded one surface to the other.

Even if you were able to separate the points mechanically, the surfaces would be poorly suited to operate in the normal manner.

Ideally, these parts are not going to break your budget. Using The Google, I [found a set](https://www.bonanza.com/listings/Honda-XL100-XL125-XL175-XL250-XL350-SL100-SL125-SL175-TL125-Contact-Point-New/492601066) for less than eight American dollars, shipped from Thailand (some delay involved!)

Comment: The delay was honestly what I was hoping to avoid, though thanks for the information! If I cant find anything at the local bike shop that will be what ill do.

Comment: Yah, replacement is the only option here. Get a new condenser to go with it.

Comment: New set of points, fitted and gapped correctly - a good set of feeler gauges needed...

Comment: Is there a general rule for selecting a new capacitor? the coil is 6v in